# Does Vuejs allow to use nested template tag?

Tags: vue.js

Is it allowed to use `<template>` tag inside template something like this?

I have to check some value.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <template v-for="category_field in category_fields">
            <template v-if="category_field.show_type == 'new-row'">
                //and also here can be more nested template tags
            </template>
            <template v-else>
                //and also here can be more nested template tags
            </template>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

I am using this system in my project and wondering whether this is correct.

Comment: I think it would be better to use ``v-content`` instead. Nesting templates inside each other is not best practice.

Comment: @AndorNémeth - `v-content` ... is not a vuejs thing

Comment: Sorry I thought I was browsing Vuetify.js tags.

Comment: Yes, you can definitely nest `<template>` tags. And, afaik, it is not and has not, ever, been considered bad practice in Vue. @AndorNémeth, please backup your claim with a link to a reputable source (preferable Vue team member) stating nesting `<templates>` is not recommended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can nest `<template>`s, and it's quite useful sometimes.

---

Vue's `<template>` is very similar to `<React.Fragment>`. It's a virtual container used for grouping or applying layout logic (using structural directives - e.g: `v-for`, `v-if`), without creating an actual DOM element.

Because it doesn't output a DOM element, it's used as a wrapper for SFC's HTML markup.

Technically, the limit on having only one child in Vue 2 was not coming from the `<template>` tag itself, but from the components, as Vue required them to have only one root element, which became the component's `$el`. [More detail here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element).

Besides the typical usage of wrapping an SFC's markup, `<template>` tags are also used for:

- combining structural directives (`v-for`, `v-if`) and letting Vue know in which order to apply the directives, as changing the order would likely change the result
- applying layout or rendering logic (e.g: `v-if`) to multiple elements at once, without having to create an actual DOM wrapper around them, particularly useful when you don't want to break the parent/child relation of DOM elements (e.g: flex or grid parent/children, `<ul>`/`<ol>` + `<li>`, `<tr>` + `<td>`, `<tbody>` + `<tr>`, etc.).
- reducing template boilerplate (e.g: moving the same `v-if` from multiple siblings on a `<template>` wrapper, so the condition is only written once).

Answer (score 1):

Try using this. `<template>` require only one child.

```
<template v-for="category_field in category_fields">
<div>
    <template v-if="category_field.show_type == 'new-row'">
        //and also here can be more nested template tags
    </template>
    <template v-else>
        //and also here can be more nested template tags
    </template>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: I forgot to add that this template already in template>div. I will update my question

Comment: And I already use this system everywhere in project I just wondered is it correct way?